# Showing "Hint" on Android (TTrackBar)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I want to display the current position in the `Hint` of a `TTrackbar` but it is never displayed on my android device. `Showhint` is `true`...
Is that an Android thing?
Any other way I can have a floating info on `TTrackBar` in Android?

Comment: Hints as we know them on Windows, are not supported on Android.

Comment: When would the hint show? On Windows, hints show when the mouse is hovered over the control. Unless there is an external mouse connected, which is [actually possible](https://www.howtogeek.com/164783/how-to-connect-mice-keyboards-and-gamepads-to-an-android-phone-or-tablet), but unusual, there is no concept of "mouse hover"

Comment: @DaveNottage: I suspect the OP is having the trackbar's "position tooltip" in mind. This is shown when the mouse is used to move the thumb (that is, while the LMB is depressed). I suppose this corresponds to dragging the thumb with a finger (thumb or not, no pun intended) on the Android device.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Which is not supported by Android ;-)